# Empty error in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotag

I used to run the GeoTagged Photos To Points tool fine. Now when I just open the tool window there is the red cross error next to the input field without me having added anything yet. When I try to run the tool with some inputs despite the warning (which is non descriptive since there is no context window that appears to tell me anything) an error dialogue box shows up but it only says error with an exclamation mark but nothing else. No description of what the issue might be. No error code like 9999 or anything.

Can you suggest what the issue might be?

Comment: If you go under the Geoprocessing window and click results you should see results window.  The errors listed for the tools you just ran can be found by expanding the tool.  What error do you see?  Also, consider turning off background processing and/disabling 64bit processing and see if that helps.

Comment: I can't even run the tool so there are no processing results to see. As soon as I try to run it that error popup with no explanatory content comes up.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your ArcGIS normal.mxt?  Here is a link   https://community.esri.com/thread/78692

Answer (score -1):

Some weeks ago, I was using arcgis 10.5, and trying to make an "extract by mask", and all my attempts are wrong. I recomend you to use another version. When I use ArcGIS 10.4, everything worked.